# Waiting for child process for a definete time

Tags: c, linux, unix, parent-child

I am trying to learn writing C programs on UNIX by doing some exercises but I got stuck on this one. In this exercise I need the parent process to wait for an exact time for child process to do something then the parent process should terminate it with giving the ID of the child process. Here is my code.

```
int main()
{
    int pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error ");
        exit(1); 
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("\n Id of child is %d ",getpid());
    }
    else
    {
        sleep 3;
        kill(0);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The problems are the following. I am not sure if sleep 3 means parent waits 3 seconds for the child process. I thought about an approach like this but it seems like it waits for the child process to terminate.

```
int Time;    
waitpid(childPid, &Time, 0); 

if (Time == 0) 
{
    printf("Correct"); 
}

if (Time == 1)      
{
    printf("Error");    
}
```

Second problem is probably more simple but I could not find out which function accomplish this. How can a child process (or a parent, does not matter much) execute a built in program?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sleep.html It's in milliseconds.

Comment: `kill(0);` doesn't do what you think it does. You might also want to enable compiler warnings.

Comment: @stackptr: What's in milliseconds?  The link you gave has the synopsis `unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);` — which looks like the seconds I'd expect. AFAIK, there isn't, and never has been, a millisecond sleep mechanism in POSIX.  There's the classic whole seconds `sleep()`; there's the microseconds `usleep()` (now deprecated, if not missing from current POSIX); and there's the modern nanoseconds `nanosleep()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, I confused `sleep` with the Windows `Sleep` which uses milliseconds. I must not be getting enough sleep.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm confused, what exactly are you trying to do? To answer your question, to execute a built-in function, you can use `system()` (it's also possible to use the `exec()` family of functions) (check http://linux.die.net/man/3/system). Using `wait()` or `waitpid()` will wait (blocking) for the child to terminate, you can use `signal()` in the child (with something like SIGCHLD) if you want to indicate something to the parent so you can have the parent terminate it instead. You can also use `alarm()` to have the child terminate after a specified amount of time.

Comment: The post you quoted is concerned with a rather particular problem, that of `[_]exit()` after a failed `execvp()`. I see no bearing on this post.

Comment: I'm sorry I just did some further research and found out I was wrong, it is okay to `exit()` from a child process. I just thought I read in a few sources that a child should use `_exit()`.

Comment: It seems like this isn't much of an answer now. Perhaps phrase is as a comment instead?

Comment: I would, but I can't comment on anything besides my own answers until I have 50 rep. (which is why I'm trying desperately hard to turn this into an answer and get some upvotes! :) ). I just hope OP helps me understand what he wants to do so I can actually provide a more meaningful answer :). If this never happens, I'll just delete my answer (until then, there is no way for me to ask OP for clarification). (Also, since your comment, I have made it slightly more of an answer :P).

Comment: Thanks much for the upvote :). Now I'm so close to 50 rep. :D!

Comment: Ok,in more simple terms what I want to accomplish is that I want parent process to wait x(x can be any number does not matter) seconds for child process while child process executes a built-in program(lets say a calculator).After x seconds parent process should give the id of child and terminate it.

Comment: Definitely check out `alarm()`.